# Adding child node with specific ID. JS and DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add child node with tag  and specific ID, and with text inside. For adding child node I use function .createElement.
After that I use setAttribute to set an ID, but it's not worked how I want.

Please, can you tell me how I can add child node with ID #just-text ? Text unit is 'Hello'.

```
() => {  const myId = document.querySelector('#append-div') const newDiv = document.createElement('div') const changeNewDiv = newDiv.setAttribute('#just-text', 'Hello')  myId.appendChild(changeNewDiv) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAttribute` returns `undefined` so when you do

```
const changeNewDiv = newDiv.setAttribute('#just-text', 'Hello')
```

`changeNewDiv` is undefined. Also `#just-text` is not a valid attribute.

Your reference to the element is *live*, so you don't need to keep updating It. The code would be like this, assuming you want to set an id of *test* and text *hello*

```js
const myId = document.querySelector('#append-div');
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'test');
newDiv.textContent = 'hello';
myId.appendChild(newDiv);
```

```html
<div id="append-div"></div>
```